# UINavigation tintColor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

How can I set gradient color in UINavigationBar?
I used this code of set the tint color on navigationBar but it does not show gradient color.

```
picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithRed:216.0/255.0 green:216.0/255.0 blue:216.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: You cannot add gradient color to a navigation bar. If you want to do so, you can add an image on to the navigation bar.

Comment: Hi Dipak,I need to put a gradient color on navigationBar of MFMailComposer.How is it possible?

Comment: use something like this
`picker.navigationBar.tintColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"path to gradient image"]];`

Answer (score 1):

```
 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
 CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
 gradient.frame = view.bounds;
 gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
 [view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Or Try this

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> // For .layer 

self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarBackgroundImage"].CGImage;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

TRy this hope this will help

Comment: gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil]; It give an error  Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion to 'id' of a non-Objective-C pointer is disallowed with Automatic Reference Counting.Please rectify it.And let me know.Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

in iOS 5

```
if ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0 ) {
    // Create resizable images
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:yourColor];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.It is not giving gradient color look on navigationBar.